# png image won't upload to background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I used [piq.codeus.net](http://piq.codeus.net/draw) to create pixel art. I tried to get the url, but it apparently has no url(I have it downloaded as background.png). I have seen people upload an image using something like *background.gif* or *bird.png*, and it works just fine, but when I tried making a [piq](http://piq.codeus.net/draw) and uploading it to my computer as *background.png* or *background.jpg*, it doesn't do anything. Here's the code I tried:

```
$('.begin').click(function() {
  $('.start').remove();
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(background.png)');}
```

Comment: Is `background.png` actually a file, and is in the same directory as the page you're trying to assign it to?

Comment: `$('.begin').click(function() { $('.start').remove();$('body').css('background-image', 'url(background.png)');})` .... you need a `)` at end

Comment: What do you mean by in the same directory? If by "actually a file," you mean it's uploaded on my computer, then yes.

Comment: The code I put above is just part of the function, I finish the .click later. This is why part of it is missing.

Comment: @redwolf10105 'in the same directory' as in, the same directory as where the Javascript is executing from. The code you have is sound, the problems must be with the file or perhaps your HTML

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)` at the end of code:

```
$('.begin').click(function() {
  $('.start').remove();
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(background.png)');});
```

Comment: No, this is only a fraction of the code, I put the ) at the end of the function.